# Live stream from GoPro to YouTube or another video service

Tags: video-quality

Here is what I would like to do.

Get the cheapest GoPro camera(s) that will live stream events to YouTube without any other equipment. I would like to record the event to YouTube as it is happening.

The bandwidth is not great but I do not care about the quality of the livestream. I'm more concerned about highest quality video recording.

Here are my questions:
1) Which GoPro camera is appropriate for this job?
2) Is it possible to select some stream settings that will sacrifice the quality of the live stream for better quality recording?

Thanks..

Comment: You will not be able to do it without additional equipment

Comment: Do I need additional equipment like these ones? http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/870452-REG/Cerevo_USA_CDP_LS01_LiveShell_USTREAM_Compatible_Device.html or https://new.livestream.com/broadcaster

Comment: Yes, you will need a device that can encode the HDMI bitstream and start a web stream with a protocol compatible with YouTube. F.e. the one you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No GoPro is appropriate for the job by itself.  Any of them (or even a basic webcam) could work as a camera, your problem is that you need something that can encode and send a stream by itself.  That is a specialized device and not something a GoPro can do.  You would want a either a device built for doing a direct stream (such as an IP camera) or you would want to have a camera with a clean HDMI (or other) output that can be fed in to a stand alone streaming device.

For the second half, recording quality and stream quality are completely and 100% independent of each other.  They are both two different captures of the same visual information, but the sensor is going to pick up maximum quality regardless of if you are recording in some low bandwidth format or not and the steam is going to run off the output which should be the high quality format regardless of what quality you are streaming at.

Comment: Thanks AJ. What do you think about wifi camcorders like this one? http://www.amazon.com/Panasonic-HC-V250K-Wi-Fi-Enabled-Camcorder/dp/B00HXE4H28/ref=sr_1_1?s=photo&ie=UTF8&qid=1412142354&sr=1-1&keywords=wifi+camcorder The first comment talks about live streaming using camcorder alone.

Comment: @Alper - as long as they meet your quality needs and can record while streaming (I would expect them too, but I'd confirm it before buying.)  then they would be part of the first class of device I described.  I don't see any reason they shouldn't work well for basic needs.